Nginx To Apache Reverse-proxy Endless 301 Redirects
I've spent about 5 hours trying to get a simple nginx to apache2 reverse proxy set up and I get dozens and dozens of redirects. It's a loop that I can't find the cause of.
I used grep to recursively search for RewriteEngine and return 301 in my etc/ and my /var/www folders. So that includes a thorough search in my apache2 files, my nginx files, and all Wordpress files. I can't find anything.
I have no .htaccess file and all plugins are disabled. There's one 301 redirect in my nginx site file. Here are my configs:
apache2.conf
# This file contains the main configuration directives for Apache2. It is used to
# configure the behavior of Apache2 server.

# Load necessary modules for MIME types
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    # Configure MIME types for compressed files
    <FilesMatch "\.php\.br$">
        AddType "text/html" .br
        AddEncoding br .br
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.html\.br$">
        AddType "text/html" .br
        AddEncoding br .br
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.js\.br$">
        AddType "text/javascript" .br
        AddEncoding br .br
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.css\.br$">
        AddType "text/css" .br
        AddEncoding br .br
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.svg\.br$">
        AddType "image/svg+xml" .br
        AddEncoding br .br
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Define runtime directory
Define APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2$SUFFIX

# Disable memory-mapping for file delivery
EnableMMAP Off

# Enable sendfile kernel support for file delivery
EnableSendfile On

# Define process ID file
Define APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid

# Set timeout for receives and sends
Timeout 100

# Enable KeepAlive for persistent connections
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 2000
KeepAliveTimeout 6

# Define default user and group
User www-data
Group www-data

# Disable hostname lookups
HostnameLookups Off

# Set error log location and log level
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Include module configuration
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf

# Set default security model
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks 
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Define access file name and prevent viewing of sensitive files
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

# Define log formats
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include generic configuration snippets
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include virtual host configurations
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# Disable ETag for better performance
FileETag None


000-default-le-ssl.conf
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin wiserrhinodesigns@gmail.com
    ServerName wiserrhinodesigns.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Logging
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # PHP-FPM via FastCGI
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>

    # Brotli Compression
    <IfModule mod_brotli.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/json application/x-font-ttf application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/x-icon
    </IfModule>

    # GZIP Compression
    <Location />
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|zip|gz|rar|bz2|7z|xz)$ no-gzip dont-vary
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>


Default (nginx - I originally had 301, but I changed it to 302 just to test things. Imagine it's a 301...)
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name wiserrhinodesigns.com www.wiserrhinodesigns.com wiserrhino.com www.wiserrhino.com;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS only if not already HTTPS
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name wiserrhinodesigns.com wiserrhino.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wiserrhinodesigns.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wiserrhinodesigns.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://wiserrhinodesigns.com:8080; # Assuming Apache is running on port 8080
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}


Can you help me with this? I'm basically a beginning developer and I can't seem to solve this 301 error.
Here is an additional screenshots that may help. It's of Dev tools:
Dev Tools
Dev Tools Details

I've grep searched for offending directives.
I've cleaned up my file system.
I've disabled all plugins.
I removed www to non-www DNS records to transfer the responsibility locally.
I've used ChatGPT to try to find and fix the error.
I've Googled and read and now my eyes are bleeding. (Same with YouTube)
I've spent 5 hours on a task everyone says only takes 10 minutes.
I've changed the listening port in Apache's port.conf to listen to 8080 only. listening on a secure port has been commented out because I don't think I need SSL on the Apache2 back-end.

